# Getting SynchronousOnlyOperation error Even after using sync_to_async in django and discord.py

Tags: python, django, python-asyncio, discord.py, django-orm

I am trying to make a discord bot for a Django website. While going to implement I came to know that Django database doesn't allow asynchronous operation, we must use thread or `sync_to_async`.

I used `sync_to_async` and it seemed to work. But then I run into a problem, I can't even figure out what is wrong with it and what is going on there.

Can anyone explain what I am doing wrong there and what is going on there?

```py
@sync_to_async
def get_customer(id):
    try:
        return Customer.objects.get(discord_id=id)
    except:
        return None
#------

@bot.command()
async def categories(ctx):
    customer = await get_customer(ctx.author.id) #this line of code works well
    categories = await sync_to_async(Category.objects.all().filter)(customer=customer)
    #categories = await sync_to_async(Category.objects.filter)(customer=customer)#I tried this also, didn't work
    print(categories) #problem is in the line
    embed = Embed(title='', description="{}".format('\n'.join([ x.name for x in categories])))
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

The traceback error I am getting is:

```py
Running bot
Ignoring exception in command categories:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/rhidwan/Desktop/personal_transaction/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 83, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "discord_bot.py", line 76, in categories
    print(categories)
  File "/Users/rhidwan/Desktop/personal_transaction/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 252, in __repr__
    data = list(self[:REPR_OUTPUT_SIZE + 1])
  File "/Users/rhidwan/Desktop/personal_transaction/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 276, in __iter__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/Users/rhidwan/Desktop/personal_transaction/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1261, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "/Users/rhidwan/Desktop/personal_transaction/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 57, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
  File "/Users/rhidwan/Desktop/personal_transaction/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1150, in execute_sql
    cursor = self.connection.cursor()
  File "/Users/rhidwan/Desktop/personal_transaction/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 24, in inner
    raise SynchronousOnlyOperation(message)
django.core.exceptions.SynchronousOnlyOperation: You cannot call this from an async context - use a thread or sync_to_async.

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/rhidwan/Desktop/personal_transaction/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 892, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "/Users/rhidwan/Desktop/personal_transaction/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 797, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "/Users/rhidwan/Desktop/personal_transaction/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 92, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: SynchronousOnlyOperation: You cannot call this from an async context - use a thread or sync_to_async.
```

Comment: have you imported ASGI

Comment: @SachinYadav I imported the line and however, it is not an import error. Cause some of the operation succeeded before.

Comment: Experiencing same issue with django 3.1

Answer (score 7):

If you still need help with the issue;

Seems like this problem is related to lazy evaluation of querysets in Django. Basically, when you call

```
MyModel.objects.filter(key=value)
```

the queryset is not immedidately evaluated, it is evaluated only when you use it, this could be iterating over it, converting it to a list, or getting a string representation of it.

In your example, even though you wrap your Django calls with sync_to_async, the queryset is evaluated when you want to print the queryset by using

```
print(categories)
```

And as it is in an async context, you get the error. To avoid it, you can force the queryset to be evaluated inside an sync_to_async, like

```
@sync_to_async
def get_categories_value(customer):
    return list(Category.objects.all().filter(customer=customer))

...

categories = await get_categories_value()
print(categories)
```

Comment: `list()` did the trick for me! thanks

Comment: Thanks for the solution. It looks like get_customer_value is missing its parameter 'customer'.

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping a regular function with `sync_to_async` makes it look asynchronous. Under the hood the function will be executed in multiple threads, therefore race conditions can occur. Django ORM has a lot of thread-usafe code (connection objects, cursors etc.), therefore it's dangerous to use it in a multi-threaded environment 'as is'.

The message you see is there to warn you about potential problems. [Here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/e4ab44a4b2ef70be09c35c9197a19fd2e993b4d6/django/utils/asyncio.py#L8) is the corresponding decorator in the source code:

```
def async_unsafe(message):
    """
    Decorator to mark functions as async-unsafe. Someone trying to access
    the function while in an async context will get an error message.
    """
```

Searching for `async_unsafe` in the Django code base will give you a good idea which parts of the ORM considered unsafe.

It is tempting to just set the `DJANGO_ALLOW_ASYNC_UNSAFE` environment variable to `true` in the project`s settings file to get rid of the problem:

```
import os
os.environ["DJANGO_ALLOW_ASYNC_UNSAFE"] = "true"
```

but this will most likely bite you brutally later. Don't do it.

I believe the only option here is to access the database directly without Django ORM. This way you'll have full control over the objects you share across threads.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem and I noticed that it happens when you try to access a model's field that is a foreign key and another key outside of the @sync_to_async.

The `__str__` of your model is probably trying to access one of those fields so when you try to print outside the @sync_to_async, you get this error.

You will have to read the values of these fields while inside the @sync_to_async and return it as a tuple along with other items

Comment: It is possible to do but avoid using "maybe" in your answer. Be Bold

Answer (score 0):

When you're calling print on the model object, Django ORM is working underneath to give you a string representation of the model, and the ORM needs to run in sync mode. So in this case, you'll need to call print using the sync_to_async wrapper.

```
await sync_to_async(print)(categories)
```