# Sync to Async Django ORM queryset length

Tags: django, django-models, python-asyncio

In asynchronous context I try to do:

```
invites = await InviteLogic.get_invites(self.app.user)
if len(invites) > 0:
    ...
```

InviteLogic is like this:

```
@sync_to_async
def get_invites(self, inviter):
    return Invite.objects.filter(inviter=inviter)
```

I get an error in line `if len(...`

`django.core.exceptions.SynchronousOnlyOperation: You cannot call this from an async context - use a thread or sync_to_async.`

How do I call len asynchronously?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63149616/getting-synchronousonlyoperation-error-even-after-using-sync-to-async-in-django) might help

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
invites = await InviteLogic.get_invites(self.app.user)
if len(await invites) > 0:
   ....
```

Comment: if len(await invites) > 0:
TypeError: object QuerySet can't be used in 'await' expression

Comment: I didn't get any errors even with await in len, can you please tell me which django version are you using?

Comment: django version 4.1.3